# Select same elements matrix in R

Tags: arrays, r, select, vector

I would like select 5 elements, no 25, as fast as possible. It takes a long time run on large vectors:

```
a = c(1,2,5,2,3)
b = c(2,4,1,4,5)
d = matrix(1:25,nrow=5,ncol=5)

result = array(NA,dim=length(a))

for (i in 1:length(a)) { result[i] = d[a[i],b[i]] }
```

OR (more slow)

```
result<-sapply(1:length(a), function(x)  d[a[x],b[x]] )
```

Comment: Can you clarify your first sentence *select 5 elements, no 25*.  I don't understand what that means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use matrix indexing:

```
d[cbind(a, b)]
# [1]  6 17  5 17 23
```

For more details, see `?Extract`, where you will find the following lines:

> A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one column for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then selects a single element of the array, and the result is a vector.

There are also a few examples in the "Examples" section at the same help page.